# Spring Boot application not reading properties value from Spring Cloud Config Server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have configured a Spring Cloud Config Server that's pulling the application values from our git repository. I can confirm that it's getting the values correctly by browsing the spring cloud url [http://localhost:8012/XXXAPIConfigServer/default]
[image]

Now in my client microservice (users-ws) I've added the following dependency and configurations

bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8012
      name: XXXAPIConfigServer
  profiles:
    active: default
```

application.yml

```
jwt:
   secretKey: v++?c2HNyw^Eq#Ba=nFTYNRuSF1bKx
   prefix: Bearer
   expirationAfterDays: 1
```

When I run the client user service I'm not getting the `expirationAfterDays` value `2` but `1`.
[image]

Additionally, I am reading those jwt values by calling a jwtclass
JwtConfig

```
package com.company.abc.api.users.configuration;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "jwt")
public class JwtConfig {

   private String secretKey;
   private String prefix;
   private int expirationAfterDays;
   private String loginUrl;

   public JwtConfig() {}

   public String getSecretKey() {
      return secretKey;
   }

   public void setSecretKey(String secretKey) {
      this.secretKey = secretKey;
   }

   public String getPrefix() {
      return prefix;
   }

   public void setPrefix(String prefix) {
      this.prefix = prefix;
   }

   public int getExpirationAfterDays() {
      return expirationAfterDays;
   }

   public void setExpirationAfterDays(int expirationAfterDays) {
      this.expirationAfterDays = expirationAfterDays;
   }

   public String getLoginUrl() {
      return loginUrl;
   }

   public void setLoginUrl(String loginUrl) {
      this.loginUrl = loginUrl;
   }

   public String getAuthorizationHeader() {
      return HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION;
   }

}
```

Here is the log file from the client api user service: (https://justpaste.it/8aeop)

Comment: Get a look at your spring boot start log, to see what happened.

Comment: What versions are you using?

Comment: @spencergibb, spring-cloud-config-server => 3.0.0-M6. For the spring-cloud-start-config, I have not added version in pom.xml so I guess the latest version 2.2.6

Comment: Since you are not sure about your client-side version and there is no action of loading config from config service, you may check the document [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Spring-Cloud-2020.0-Release-Notes#breaking-changes), and enable the bootstrap manually by setting `spring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled=true` or to include the new `spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap` in your POM file.

Comment: I'll do further digging into the configurations. The same config is applied to Zuul API GW and it's getting the values from the configserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what's causing the problem. I have the same bootstrap.yml config with Zuul API Gateway and I noticed that I'm using the following versions:

```
spring-boot-starter-parent => 2.3.6.RELEASE
sprint-cloud.version => Hoxton.SR9
```

Where as in User Web Service I'm using (not working)

```
spring-boot-starter-parent => 2.4.0
sprint-cloud.version => 2020.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```